# How to obtain an average of multipile values? [Python]

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to find an average score(value) for a key(name) which has multiple values and the dictionary looks like this:

```
James Scored: 7
Mason Scored: 3
James Scored: 2
Mason Scored: 5
```

Already did append if same key exists, so now I just need to figure out a loop in order to find an average but I've no idea why the code below doesnt work for me. Kind of new to this so an explanation would be great.

Code I've managed to produce so far:

```
dictionary = {}
#opens the file with the data
f = open('ClassA.txt', 'r')
#a empty dictionar created
d = {}
#loop to split the data in the ext file
for line in f:
        name, scores = line.strip().split(':')
        dictionary[name.strip()] = scores.strip()
        columns = line.split(": ")
        #identifies the key and value with either 0 or 1
        name = columns[0]
        scores = columns[1].strip()
        #appends values if a key already exists
        d.setdefault(name, []).extend(scores)
for scores in sorted(d.items()):
        average = sum(scores)/len(scores)
        print ("{} Scored: {}".format(name,average))
```

Wanted output would be:

```
James: 4.5
Mason: 4
```

Comment: Wild guess: try `for score, v in sorted(d.items()):`

Comment: appears the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320711/how-to-find-an-average-of-multiple-values-for-a-key).

Comment: To be clear, is your code crashing with an error message, or producing no output, or what? I figured your original code would crash because `v` isn't defined anywhere, and I'm surprised because you seem to be saying that there's no change at all.

Comment: Shouldn't your second 'for' loop create the array of scores 'v'. Then the line 'average = sum(v)/len(v)' should work?

Comment: @Barun Sharma Simillar homework task, went through all the answers there but I really don't want to use the `lambada` function, I don't think it would be good for me to use a function which I just dont quite grasp.

Comment: @Kevin The output is nothing which is the problem, CodyF the second loop is the bit im not sure about I tried to create a loop which sorted each value for every key but obviously failed.

Comment: @princesedafsdfasd That's a real lame excuse. It takes 10 minutes to check and write a sample code line to grasp `lambda`. And I would advise you must learn it. It's widely used and a good to know python strength.
Anyway, I think above comments must have helped. I tried with the changes, it works. I am sure the problem is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `dictionary` because you don't need it, strip "Scored" from the end of each user's name, convert `scores` to a number before adding it to your dict, use `append` instead of `extend`, and unpack `d.items` into `name` and `v` instead of just `scores`.

```
#opens the file with the data
f = open('ClassA.txt', 'r')
#a empty dictionar created
d = {}
#loop to split the data in the ext file
for line in f:
        columns = line.split(": ")
        #identifies the key and value with either 0 or 1
        name = columns[0].rpartition(" ")[0]
        scores = float(columns[1].strip())
        #appends values if a key already exists
        d.setdefault(name, []).append(scores)
for name, v in sorted(d.items()):
            average = sum(v)/len(v)
            print ("{} Scored: {}".format(name,average))
```

Result:

```
James Scored: 4.5
Mason Scored: 4.0
```

Comment: Hey, works perfect however how would I go about printing the average in order from highest to lowest ? i tried this `print ("{} Scored: {}".format(name,max(average)))`  but a type error popped up ;/

Comment: You can change the way the results are sorted by specifying a different `key` argument in the `sorted` function. `for name, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: sum(item[1])/len(item[1])):`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your variable v is not defined. Besides that I think the dictionary "dictionary" and the dictionary "d" are the same? It looks like they should have the same content.

Anyway, try this in your last code block:

```
for name, scores in d.iteritems():
        average = sum(scores)/len(scores)
        print ("{} Scored: {}".format(name, average))
```

`for name, scores in d.iteritems():`

returns e.g.:
`("Josh":[1,2,3])`

per iteration.